# Area 51 site stats are weirdly formatted on beta sites in new design

Tags: bug, design

There is some space missing between the table columns which looks especially weird if most of the values are four digit values. This just looks wrong without spacing. A bit of column spacing would be great there. An empty row after the actual stats would also be an improvement.

[image: Area 51 stats on IoT.se]